# Targeting 2nd ul and 5th child

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have two UL's on a page with the same ID. I would like to target the 5th li in the 2nd UL. Is it possible to do something like this?

html:

```
<ul id="homepage-blockpaging">
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
</ul>

<ul id="homepage-blockpaging">
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
</ul>
```

proposed jquery:

```
$('#homepage-blockpaging:eq(1) li:eq(4)').after('<li>New Item</li>');
```

Preferred outcome:

```
<ul id="homepage-blockpaging">
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>New Item</li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
<li>Item </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why do you have two elements on a page with the same id? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp You are making life hard for yourself from the get-go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you'll want to change `homepage-blockpaging` to a class, since you can't have two elements with the same ID in HTML!

Then, you can accomplish what you want this way:

```
$(".homepage-blockpaging:eq(1)") // get 2nd ul
    .find("li:eq(4)") // get the 5th li inside it
    .after( // create a new li element
        $("<li>")
            .text("New Item")
    );
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/4cckhg31/)'s a demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the 2nd ul using: `$("ul")[1]`

Then, to find the 5th li, you can use the jQuery `find()` method along with `:eq` But to use them you have to convert it back to a jQuery object.

So, finally you end up with something like:

```
$($("ul")[1]).find("li:eq(4)").after('<li>New Item</li>');
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: The code does exactly what you asked. Were you trying to imply something else?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Added an explanation. Thanks for the info.